# Evaluating if statement with single char C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean

I am trying to evaluate a single char:

```
bool repeat = true;
while (repeat)

//code

char x;
    cout << "Would you like to tansfer another file? Y/N ";
    cin >> x;

    if (x == 'y' || x == 'Y')
        repeat = true;
    if (x == 'n' || x == 'N')
        repeat = false;
    else
        throw "Input error";
```

I keep getting Input Error as my console output. Any ideas why? I can't get the while loop to repeat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an `else` here:

```
if (x == 'n' || x == 'N')
```

should be:

```
else if (x == 'n' || x == 'N')
```

and you need to add braces after the `while` to encompass the input and `if` statements.

Answer (score 4):

You forget braces `{}` after `while`:

```
while (repeat)
{

  char x;
  cout << "Would you like to tansfer another file? Y/N ";
  cin >> x;

  if (x == 'y' || x == 'Y')
      repeat = true;
  else
  if (x == 'n' || x == 'N')
      repeat = false;
  else
      throw "Input error";

}
```